# Login for two different users using laravel

Tags: laravel

I have made two login system. a) for Users and b) for Administrator.
But the problem is the *app/config/auth.php* in laravel has the default `model=>'User'` and
`table=>'users'` and I have two models and tables for different users.

How can I use the two different models and tables for login?

Comment: As the admin is a user too, you're sure about that data-model? There could be a table with usser-rights & then you can work normally with routes

Comment: I wonder if you would be better of by using the same table for both users and admins - and have a nullable link to an admin-rights-table or a non-nullable link to general-users-rights-table.

Comment: @Adimeus thanks for your suggestion but for the moment i need to use different model and tabel if there's a way to change the attributes of auth.php but however i've tried coding Config::set('auth.model','Admin'); but failed..

Answer (score 1):

**What you're doing is considered bad practice** - you should take a look at role based permission systems or helpers. I have a few suggestions for you:

- [Sentry](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry) - Most popular, comes with permission system and roles
- [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) - Let's you add role based permissions

You should never repeat stuff for the same type of resource - that's like having a blog where you have a table for each category, it just doesn't really work and it's incredibly time consuming to keep up to date and in sync.

You should change your style right now, take the opportunity, it will save you time in the long run, believe me.